# GoogleSignInResult returns null GoogleSignInAccount in production

Tags: android, google-signin

I am following [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java) to integrate google authentication in my app. It is working fine in debug apks, but when released, it is failing every time.

I have registered both debug and relese SHA-1 key on cloud platform.

code snippet for reference-

```
private void someMethid(){        
String languageURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile.language.read";
String genderURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read";
String birthdayURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read";
GoogleSignInOptions option = new 
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(
                    new Scope(languageURL),
                    new Scope(genderURL),
                    new Scope(birthdayURL)
            )
            .build();
    client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, option);
    signIn();
}

private void signIn() {

    Intent signInIntent = client.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    GoogleSignInAccount acct = null;
    try {
        acct = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        if (acct != null) {
            fetchData(acct);
        }
        else {
            showDialogMessage("Email verification failed", "failed to get Google account information", false);
            client.revokeAccess();
            client.signOut();
        }
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        showDialogMessage("Email verification failed", "failed to get Google account information", false);
        client.revokeAccess();
        client.signOut();
    }
```

The SignIn prompt opens, does ask for google account, but does not ask for permissions of the requested scopes and retuns null for GoogleSignInAccount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `When released`, do you mean when you install the app from Google Play? If you're using ["Play App Signing"](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en), you need to add the signing key from the Google Play Console, not from your repository/ keystore. This is because Google Play signs the app on your behalf.

**Diagnosing your problem:** It looks like the app was signed with a different key to the one the authentication service is expecting, so the service rejects it. It was resigned with you knowing about it.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en

If that doesn't work, please give more detail :). Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 2):

After Uploading to play store, Play store generate its own SH1 which we have to replace in second key in google console.

Go to google console>app signing> copy SH1 generate by console. Add that in google sign in console replace it from 2nd key.

[image]